# Show a limited time Message wxPython

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, wxpython, message

I build an application in wxPython and in the application I want to show a message for a limited time and then, it will be disappeared by itself (the user of the application doesn't have to nothing to make it disappear)
I tried to do it like that, but it didn't closed by itself.

```
dialog = wx.MessageDialog(None,'message', wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION | wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
threading.Timer(2.0, dialog.Destroy).start()
dialog.ShowModal()
```

I also tried to do it like that and it either didn't do nothing:

```
dialog = wx.MessageDialog(None,'message', wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION | wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
threading.Timer(2.0, dialog.EndModal,args=wx.ID_OK).start()
dialog.ShowModal()
```

Comment: You really need to describe a context for this, before people can offer an answer which is appropriate.

Comment: I guess the modal MessageDialog catches all the application events, also the timer events. 
You could subclass a dialog and place the timer inside that dialog so it can close itself.

Comment: I don't sure because I tried to do it also with a StaticText and the Timer still didn't to anything and it wasn't destroyed. @Mace

Comment: When you call ShowModal, the main thread stops and waits for return inside ShowModal. Calling Destroy from another thread may not have the expected return results for the main thread to send the necessary events to close the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough context to see what is the problem with your timer. You could try this however.

```
import wx

# ================================================================================
class TimedDialog(wx.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TimedDialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.SetSize((400, 300))
        self.SetTitle('Please wait!')
        self.Centre()

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer)

        self.timer.Start(2000)  # 2 second interval

    def OnTimer(self, event):
        self.Close()


# ================================================================================
class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):

        self.SetSize((300, 200))
        self.SetTitle('app')
        self.Centre()
        self.btn = wx.Button(self, -1, "click Me")
        self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClicked)

    def OnClicked(self, event):
        dlg = TimedDialog(self)
        dlg.ShowModal()


def main():

    app = wx.App()
    ex = Example(None)
    ex.Show()
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: But, I forgot to say, I need to do this action from another thread and not from the main thread and I got the exception "timer can only be started from the main thread". There is a way to solve it?

Comment: I think you can do this by sending events betweem threads. Maybe this can help you 'wx.PostEvent and Threads'  http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts. I read about it but I didn't understand how to do it in the example that you posted. can you show me please? @Mace

Comment: I would suggest the following: The example 'wx.PostEvent and Threads' is ready and runnable. Copy it from the site and try to figure out how it works. Then step by step integrate a simple dialog and timer into this program the way you like it..

Answer (score 0):

I got your dialog to close using `dialog.DestroyLater` but it was not consistent, anywhere from on time to 20 seconds late. Hardly what you wanted.
This is something I put together 2 years ago but can no longer remember why.
It's a bit over the top but hopefully it will help.

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Busy Dialog",size=(500,200))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.log = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, size=(400,100),style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.VSCROLL)
        self.button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Click me")
        sizer.Add(self.log, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)
        sizer.Add(self.button, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton)

    def OnButton(self,event):
        dlg = Busy(parent = self.panel)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        if dlg.result_text:
            self.log.AppendText("Text Input: "+dlg.result_text+"\n")
        dlg.Destroy()

class Busy(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, "Busy", size= (420,240))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self,wx.ID_ANY)
        self.label = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Input", pos=(20,20))
        self.textinput = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, value="", pos=(80,20), size=(300,-1))
        self.gauge = wx.Gauge(self.panel,size=(300,20),pos=(80,80), style=wx.GA_HORIZONTAL)
        self.livelabel = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Time to live:", pos=(80,110))
        self.lltime = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="30", pos=(160,110))
        self.saveButton =wx.Button(self.panel, label="Save Input", pos=(80,160))
        self.closeButton =wx.Button(self.panel, label="Cancel", pos=(180,160))
        self.timeoutButton =wx.Button(self.panel, label="Timer Off", pos=(280,160))
        self.saveButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.SaveBusyString)
        self.closeButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnQuit)
        self.timeoutButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnNoTimeout)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnQuit)
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER,self.OnTimer, self.timer)
        self.lifetimer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER,self.OnLifeTimer, self.lifetimer)
        self.timer.Start(100)
        self.lifetimer.Start(1000)
        self.timeoutbutton_pressed = False
        self.gauge.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 127, 255, 255)) #Slate Blue
        self.gauge.SetRange(100)
        self.gauge.SetValue(0)
        self.life = 30
        self.direction = 1
        self.result_text = None
        self.Show()

    def OnTimer(self, evt): #Update gauge
        x = int(self.gauge.GetValue())
        if x == 0:
            self.direction = 1
        elif x == 100:
            self.direction = -1
        x+=self.direction
        self.gauge.SetValue(x)

    def OnLifeTimer(self, evt): #Update time to live
        if self.timeoutbutton_pressed == True:
            return
        self.life -= 1
        self.lltime.SetLabelText(str(self.life))
        if self.life < 1:
            self.result_text = self.textinput.GetValue()
            self.OnQuit(None)

    def OnNoTimeout(self, evt): # toggle time to live
        if self.timeoutbutton_pressed == False:
            self.timeoutbutton_pressed = True
            self.timeoutButton.SetLabel("Timer On")
        else:
            self.timeoutbutton_pressed = False
            self.timeoutButton.SetLabel("Timer Off")

    def OnQuit(self, event):
        self.timer.Stop()
        self.lifetimer.Stop()
        self.Destroy()

    def SaveBusyString(self, event): # return input
        self.result_text = self.textinput.GetValue()
        self.timer.Stop()
        self.lifetimer.Stop()
        self.Destroy()

app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]